# Loading Data into the application from GUI using Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, selenium-webdriver, automation, rake-task

**Problem**:

Hi everyone, I am currently building an automation suite using Ruby-Selenium Webdriver-Cucumber to load data into the application using it's GUI. I've take input from mainframe *.txt* files. The scenarios are like to create a customer and then load multiple accounts for them as per the data provided in the inputs.

**Current Approach**

Execute the scenario using the rake task by passing line number as parameter and the script is executed for only one set of data.

To read the data for a particular line, I'm using below code:

```
  File.readlines("#{file_path}")[line_number.to_i - 1]
```

My purpose of using line by line loading is to keep the execution running even if a line fails to load.

**Shortcomings**

Supposed I've to load 10 accounts to a single customer. So my current script will run 10 times to load each account. I want something that can load the accounts in a single go.

**What I am looking for**

To overcome the above shortcoming, I want to capture the entire data for a single customer from the file like accounts etc and load them into the application in a single execution.

Also, I've to keep track on the execution time and memory allocation as well.

Please provide your thoughts on this approach and any suggestions or improvements are welcomed. (Sorry for the long post)

Comment: `"#{file_path}"` is exactly the same as `file_path`, assuming it is a String.  So might as well use the simpler form.

Comment: I don't understand your workflow, but if you're loading multiple lines from that file, why not read it into an array once, and then use that array in memory?  Also, if you only want to get 1 line per file read, you can easily write a method that reads line by line and stops when you've found the desired line -- this will save an average of half a file read.

Comment: @KeithBennett -> I already have the working script with line by line execution. I'm trying to build something which can capture the data at once for a customer and load it into the application. I can do that easily but I would need to do it in the quickest possible time as file size can be huge.

Comment: What do you mean by "line by line execution"?  One line per invocation?

Comment: If so, that is where I would start.  I would run your entire set in a single invocation.  There are ways you can deal with failures, e.g. log a message, etc.  Invoking your program once for each input is overkill and IMO a bad idea.

Comment: @KeithBennett -> so you suggest reading the file at once and then go ahead with the execution instead of reading a line and then loading it in the application ? right ? I was trying to avoid this because reading the entire file at once will be time and memory consuming.

Comment: When you call File.readlines, you *are* loading the entire file into memory.  So instead of doing it many times, you could do it just once.  I may not be understanding your workflow though -- how are you getting the other data?

Comment: How about loading data line by line using File.foreach so as to keep low use of memory ?

Comment: My flow is to enter certain fields in the ui and submit... now there are records in a text file, each line containing one record. I am loading one line at a time using File.foreach or File.readlines and enter the data in the ui and submit and repeating this process for all the records in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is break this down into steps -- as you said in your comment, but more formally here:

1. Get the data to apply to all records. Put up a page with the
   necessary information (or support command line specification if not
   too much?).
2. For each line in the file, do the following (automated):
           Get the web page for inputting its data;
           Fill in the fields;
           Submit the form

Given this, I'd say the 'for each line' instruction should definitely be reading a line at a time from the file using `File.foreach` or similar.

Is there anything beyond this that needs to be taken into account?

Comment: Good.  After breaking it down into steps, when you start implementing those steps as code, think about how to code discrete methods, each having a single purpose.  This will simplify the problem.

Comment: Did that already.. just wanted to check with know how other people will deal with similar problems and if my approach is accurate enough.

Comment: @yudi2312 I see you're a fairly new user. If you haven't already, could you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and, if you feel it's appropriate, follow the instructions there?